# SQL Server Dynamic Condition for Where

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Assuming I have two tables:

- Students : Id, Name, Age, Class, etc
- Conditions : Id, Condition

The Column Conditions.Condition contains a SQL Condition for example "std.Age >2" or "std.Class = 3"

I want somthing that does the following:

```
SELECT std.Id as StudentId, con.Id as ConId
FROM   Students as std,
       Condition as con
WHERE  con.Condition
```

Maybe a function that takes Student Id?

How do I achieve this?

---

Students:

```
1 , Yossi, 25, 3..
2 , David, 22, 3..
3 , Jhon, 5, 2..
4 , Smith, 25, 4..
```

Conditions:

```
1 , Age > 3
2 , Class = 4
3 , Name LIKE '%i%'
```

result would be (Condition, Studnet):

```
(1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) // all are older than 3
(2,4)                   // only Smith is in class 4
(3,1) (3,2) (3,4)       // all except jhon have an i in their name
```

Comment: how many conditions will there in condition table ?

Comment: not too many... but i want them to be dynamic

Comment: you want something like sql quere will check all the condition at the time of execution , right ?

Comment: Also can you put some data here so that i can get batter idea

Comment: Will you need complex conditions? Like 1:n relationship between table student and table condition? If are you are do foresee usage of AND / OR / NOT? The answer complexity will depend on the needs.

Comment: @LuisLL no. i just need pairs of student, and condition. (StudentId,ConditionId) thats it

Comment: @AK_ check my ans . it is working properly .

Comment: @HirenDhaduk you didnt understand the question... i don't want the students that match any of the conditions. I want a pairing of Students and the Conditions they answer to. (Student.Id, Condition.Id)

Comment: can you please put output in to your question ?

Comment: @AK_ I edited my answer . check it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following Query :

```
DECLARE @CONDITIONS varchar(max) =
REPLACE(REPLACE((
SELECT'UNION ALL SELECT ID AS STUDENTID , ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR , ID ) + ' AS CONDITIONID FROM STUDENTS WHERE ' + CONDITION + ' ' 
FROM CONDITION
FOR XML PATH('')
) , '&LT;' , '<') , '&GT;' , '>') 

SET @CONDITIONS = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@CONDITIONS , 11 , LEN(@CONDITIONS)))

EXEC(@CONDITIONS)
```

This is more generalize way to apply condition . if you want to apply only one condition then add where clause in query from where we fetch all the condition . you can run this query for one or more condition . currently i have written this query which apply all the conditions .

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/682b8/2)

Comment: @AK_ did you check my answer ? is that you want ?

Comment: tell me if you need any further customization or this query is perfect ?

Comment: I'm evaluating your answer for my real use case now... I'll probably use something slightly different though... but it's a nice solution...

Comment: Thanks , i always tries to find best solution .

Comment: the thing is, in reality I'm using NHibernate to access the DB. My initial direction was that it might be possible to do with a 'JOIN', but if the only solution is a 'UNION' of all the quarries for the conditions, then I'll just create them separately and run them using multi query or something.

Comment: please don't forgot to accept this ans if it help you so that it will be helpful to others . BTW i have spent lot of time to complete this query .

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to build a string, which includes condition, and then EXECUTE it.    This is what is called "dynamic SQL"

As an example:

```
 DECLARE @sql Varchar(400)

 SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ' + condition
  FROM Conditions
 WHERE cond_key = 1

 -- This will yield you a full SQL statement, if the condition record
 -- is there.

 EXECUTE(@sql)            -- And this will execute it
```

Comment: this one only work to return just one row. The request is for multiple rows.

Comment: That is not true:  it will execute the constructed SQL statement, and return whatever that statement would return.  The example was only to illustrate how to do dynamic SQL.

Comment: I'm sorry, there is a coment by HirenDhaduk that he is asking for pairing Students and the Conditions they answer to. Your where clause to create the dynamic SQL constrain it to just one condition.

Comment: I was responding to the OP, not some other guy's comments.

Comment: That is the direction im going towards but im having trouble phrasing the query...

Comment: @ak_ If you want to open up a chat channel, I'll try to give you a hand.